# Indy10 cookies with Delphi 2010 - cookies not being sent

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, session-cookies, indy10

I am having a problem trying to send a cookie using Delphi 2010 and Indy 10.5.8.  Code below shows the procedures

being used to perform an initial login and user authentication - verify serial, then user login, then poll for any
other logged in users.

Step 2 is to login again and query the user forum database.  It is the second step that is failing due to no cookie being sent.

See the attached JPG for what happens (contents of 'AllPosts').  That figure shows the diagnostics I have the program
generating as it attempts to reach the forum database.  The forum returns the cookie information when I log
in, but the Indy10 Put command does not send the Cookie back in subsequent calls to the forum.

Here are excepts of the code used to access the forum.  The first 4 procedures relate to logging into
the lobby and the last 2 are for accessing the forum.  In the attached JPG you can see that the first call to
TransmitPost successfully logins in the forum and gets the Cookie in the response.  The subsequent call to
TransmitPost receives the response error number 46, which indicates that the Cookie is missing.  Both these
calls are made from the routine ViewForums below.

A cookie manager has been set up at design time.

```
// ****************************************************************************
procedure TNetPlayForumForm.TransmitRequest(const ReturnCode: Boolean = True;
                                        const ShowResponse: Boolean = True);
var
  Response: String;
begin
  Response := IdHTTPForum.Get(IPAdd);

if ShowResponse then AllPosts.Lines.Add(Response)
else GoodMessage('Ready.');

if ReturnCode then ResponseInteger := ExtractNumber(Response, ResponseData)
else
begin        // No return code for some transmissions.
  ResponseInteger := 0;
  ResponseData := Response;
end;
// ****************************************************************************
procedure TNetPlayForumForm.QVerifySerial;
begin
  BusyMessage('Verifying the serial number: ' + SerialNumber);
  AllPosts.Lines.Add('Verifying the serial number: ' + SerialNumber);
  IPAdd := rsNetPlayForumServer + Format(rsVerifySerial, [SerialNumber]);
  TransmitRequest;
end;
// ****************************************************************************
procedure TNetPlayForumForm.QLoginUser;
begin
  BusyMessage('Logging in: ' + UserName + ' on port ' + MyPortNumber + '.');
  AllPosts.Lines.Add('Logging in: ' + UserName + ' on port ' + MyPortNumber +
                     '.');
  IPAdd := rsNetPlayForumServer +
           Format(rsLoginUser, [SerialNumber, UserName, Password, MyPortNumber]);
  TransmitRequest;
end;
// ****************************************************************************
procedure TNetPlayForumForm.QPollTheLobby;
begin
  BusyMessage('Polling the forum for players on-line.');
  IPAdd := rsNetPlayForumServer + Format(rsPollTheLobby, [SerialNumber]);
  AllPosts.Lines.Add('Polling the forum for players on-line.');
  AllPosts.Lines.Add('IP addresses for players on-line:');
  TransmitRequest(False);
end;
// ****************************************************************************
procedure TNetPlayForumForm.TransmitPost;
var
  Response: String;
  RawHeaders: TIdHeaderList;
  Indx: Integer;
  RawHeader: String;
  Nam: String;
  PostStream: TStream;
begin
  PostStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  Response := IdHTTPForum.Put(IPAdd, PostStream);
  PostStream.Free;
  RawHeaders := IdHTTPForum.Request.RawHeaders;

  for Indx := 0 to RawHeaders.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Nam := RawHeaders.Names[Indx];
    RawHeader := 'Request: ' + Nam + ' = ' + RawHeaders.Values[Nam];
    AllPosts.Lines.Add(RawHeader);
  end;

  AllPosts.Lines.Add(Response);
  ResponseInteger := ExtractNumber(Response, ResponseData);
  RawHeaders := IdHTTPForum.Response.RawHeaders;

  for Indx := 0 to RawHeaders.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Nam := RawHeaders.Names[Indx];
    RawHeader := 'Response: ' + Nam + ' = ' + RawHeaders.Values[Nam];
    AllPosts.Lines.Add(RawHeader);
  end;
end;
// ****************************************************************************
procedure TNetPlayForumForm.ViewForums;
// ****************************************************************************
// Forum elements: This, Parent, Forum, Topic.  There can be multiple topics.
// A forum element contains: ID, Status, Type, Name
//                           Poster, Description, Topics, Posts
//                           LastPostDate, LastPostUser, Views, Replies, URL.
// ****************************************************************************
begin
  IPAdd := rsNetPlayForumAccess +
           Format(rsLoginToForum, [SerialNumber, UserName, Password]);
  TransmitPost;
  IPAdd := rsNetPlayForumAccess + rsViewForums;
  TransmitPost;
end;
// ****************************************************************************
```

I would appreciate any advice you might have as to how I can insert the cookie information into subsequent calls to the forum so as to appease the forum's gatekeeper.

[image: image of diagnostic messages]

Comment: The cookie expires 01-Jan-1970, have you tried to debug into the Indy source to see if this might be the cause of the missing reponse cookies?